# UIPickerView horizontal change width issue

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to set a UIPickerView from vertical to horizontal.
I have rotate the UIPickerView and the reusable view but I can't increase the width of the rotated UIPickerView.

I know I am missing something but since I am new in iOS I can figure it out. Thanks a lot

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
    let pickerData = ["pick a font","pick a font 1","pick a font 2","pick a font 3","pick a font 4","pick a font 4","pick a font 4","pick a font 4","pick a font 4","pick a font 4","pick a font 4"]
    let customWidth : CGFloat =  40
    let customHeight : CGFloat = 180

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pickerView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(-90 * (Float.pi / 180)))
        //Trying to increase the width but this line is not doing anything.
        pickerView.frame = CGRect(x: -100, y: 0, width: view.frame.width + 200 , height: 30)
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return customHeight
    }
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return customWidth
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 180, height: customHeight))
        view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(90 * (Float.pi / 180)))
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: customHeight / 2 - 15, width: 180
            , height: 30))

        label.text = pickerData[row]
        label.textColor = .white

        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: .bold)
        view.addSubview(label)

        return view
    }
}
```

Comment: After a lot of time I figure out "accidently" that it was a constraint issue.

Comment: What was the constraint issue? I'm having the same problem I think.

Comment: @VagueExplanation : It's a lot time ago and I can really remember.I remember that I was looking on that tutorial and help me a lot https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8EuoHAw_PBk&t=1s .

Comment: It looks like to me setting constraints at all mess it up trying to set the frame. I could not set the widths and heights of custom UILabel views added to the picker view, so I used this function to set the height https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate/1614386-pickerview

Comment: I remember that I didn't use that function. But if you haven't watch the tutorial, please watch it because it explains exactly how to set up a UIPickerView Horizontal.

Comment: I have watched the video, but unfortunately setting the frame for the label and custom view for each UIPickerView view has no effect. However otherwise the tutorial was very helpful, and using that extra method to set the height solved my problem.

Comment: @VagueExplanation. Nice to hear that you found a solution like this I will keep it on mind in case of future problem.Glad that worked out. If you want, I can send you my project to check how I did it. I remember using it on a pop up viewController